# How to hide any row in a table whose third cell value does not match a given string in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

If i have a table:

```
<table id="myTable">
     <tr>
         <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>NoMatch</td><td>4</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>Match</td><td>4</td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

I have been trying:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input#myInput').keyup(function (val) {
      // for each third td of each row, if this value does not contain: this.val() then hide it
    });
});
```

Comment: So you would want the `NoMatch` row to hide if you typed `Match` in the `input`?

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker, Yes that is what i am aiming for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var $cells = $('#myTable tr td:nth-child(3)'),
    $hidden = $();

$('#myInput').keyup(function () { 
    var search = this.value;

    var $to_hide = $cells.filter(function() {
        return $(this).text() !== search;
    }).parent();

    $hidden.not($to_hide.get()).show();
    $hidden = $to_hide.hide();
});
```

I assumed that when you say *contains*, you mean that the text has to be equal to the provided input (otherwise `NoMatch` and `Match` would not make sense). But if the content of cell just has to contain the search string as substring, you can use [`.indexOf()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/PEpqz/)

There are other things you have to consider, like what should happen when the search string is empty, but this is for you to play around ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use "this" in your key up event handler to get the value of the input.

```
       $(document).ready(function () { 
            $('input#myInput').keyup(function () { 
                //add if statement 
                alert($(this).val()); 
            }); 
        });
```

Not quite sure what you are trying to do with the table.  There is not enough information.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kasdega/mCU2K/)

**HTML**

```
<table id="myTable">
     <tr>
         <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>NoMatch</td><td>4</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>Match</td><td>4</td>
     </tr>
</table>

<input id="myInput"/>
```

**Javascript/Jquery**

```
$('#myInput').keyup(function () {
    var me = $(this);
    var val = me.val();

    $("#myTable tr").each(function() {
        var tr = $(this);
        var td = tr.find("td:eq(2)");

        if(td.text().substring(0, val.length) === val) {
            tr.show();
        } else {
            tr.hide();
        }
    });
});
```